# How to create an array of linked lists in java

Tags: java

Hello StackOverflow community , I am trying to create the following diagram in java :
[image]

There is **Cellule** Class ( cell which contains : an **unknown type** attribut named **val** , an **integer** named **val** , and a **pointer** to another Cell named **next** ) , and the DictionnaireHacahge Class which declares a **pointer to an array of Cellule** named **dictH** which I am trying to **instanciate** further in the **constructor **.
PS: the two class are in the same package inf353 .
but when I am trying to code it with java I am facing a problem in the **constructor** :
[image: the constructor]
the error :
[image]

and here is the  code :
Cellule.java :

```
package inf353;

public class Cellule<T>{
        public T val;
        public int index ;
        public Cellule next;

        public Cellule() {
            super();
        }
```

DictionnaireHachage class :

```
package inf353;

public class DictionnaireHachage implements Dictionnaire{
    Cellule<String>[] dictH ;
    int index = 0;
    public void DictionnaireHachage(){
        dictH = new Cellule<String>[100];
        index=0;
    }
```

Comment: What the error mentionnned by the red underlining ?

Comment: - I added the error screenshot 
- I tried to read the  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580454/generic-array-creation-with-diamond-operator twice but I don't think it's the same problem or I can't see it , if you could explain it I would appreciate it

Comment: @OukkalYacine this is a better dupe, but I couldn't find it before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810074/array-of-generic-list. And even spot-on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217065/cannot-create-an-array-of-linkedlists-in-java (it even asks about linked lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to create an array with diamond:

```java
Cellule<String>[] arr = new Cellule<String>[10];
```

But the good news. We all know (I hope), that diamond operations are live only at compile time. At runtime there're always `Object`. So you can create the array not using diamond:

```java
Cellule<String>[] arr = new Cellule[10];
```

***P.S.** It is better to use `List<Cellule<String>>` instead*